# Format text extracted from HTML

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am getting the text from this HTML with one line:

```
<label class="product_title"> 
  "TEXT 1" 
  <br> 
  "TEXT2" 
</label>
```

My code is:

```
title = amazon.find_element_by_css_selector(
  'div > div > label').get_attribute('innerText')
```

**Current output:**

```
TEXT
TEXT1
```

**Desired output:**

```
TEXT TEXT1
```

**Question**

How do I obtain my desired output?

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780904/removing-unwanted-characters-from-a-string-in-python/

Comment: Answer below works and i think is easier solution but thanks for link!

Comment: It's the same answer. What I am pointing out to you is you should expect your question to be deleted shortly as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing unwanted characters from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780904/removing-unwanted-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the new line character with space as below :

```
title = amazon.find_element_by_css_selector('div > div > label').get_attribute('innerText').replace("\n", " ")
```

Comment: glad to hear :)