# How to extract text from an HTML node and maintain the correct space formatting with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to get the text value inside of a `div`. You can think of it like a text area, where you can do like this:

```
let inputArea = document.getElementById("text-area");
let text = inputArea.value;

text
// Expected result:
// Hello
//
// Hello
//
// Hello
//
// Hello
```

Unfortunately, I don't have a text area and I can't do that. So what here's what I did:

(1) Get the HTML node where I need to extract the text (`var bodyHtml..`)

(2) Convert the HTML node to string (calling `extractStringFromNode()..`)

(3) Extract the string out of the returned string (calling `extractContentFromString()..`)

My problem is that I lose the "text formatting". The `let text` (code above) contains the value of the `inputArea` with the proper formatting. I lose this when I try to reproduce it using my implementation (code below).

What is the right way to solve this?

---

```
var OriginalText;

function parseText(event) {
                // get text
                var bodyHtml = event.composeView.getBodyElement();
                var stringBodyHtml = extractStringFromNode(bodyHtml);
                console.log(stringBodyHtml)
                var text = extractContentFromString(stringBodyHtml);
                OriginalText = text;
                console.log(text);

                // now parse it 
                format(text);
            }


// extract text from html
        function extractContentFromString(s) {
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerHTML = s;
            return span.textContent || span.innerText;
        };

        // from html node to string

        function extractStringFromNode ( node ) {
            var tmpNode = document.createElement( "div" );
            tmpNode.appendChild( node.cloneNode( true ) );
            var str = tmpNode.innerHTML;
            tmpNode = node = null; // prevent memory leaks in IE
            return str;
        }

        // Expected result: HelloHelloHelloHello
```

Comment: You "lose" your formatting - what formatting? You're trying to pull text from a Div, right?

Comment: Ie. I cannot distinguish new paragraphs.

Comment: @zfrisch looks like similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47811878/format-text-extracted-from-html

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS property [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) and set it to `pre`. This will preserve line breaks, however, you must place it in every place you want to have the text with similar spacing.

```js
let div = document.querySelector("div"); 
//this div has CSS styling white-space: pre

span = document.body.appendChild( document.createElement("span") );
//this span does not

span.textContent = div.textContent;
//div will be "formatted" with line breaks. Span will not.
```

```css
div { 
white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div>This
Is
A
Demo
</div>
<hr/>
```

Comment: makes sense, but 

`<div>This
Is
A
Demo
</div>`

 it's not my case. I have nested <span> inside the outer div.

Comment: Can you grab that span instead of the div? It's the same concept. Just change the selector to match your span.